# Get list of added artifacts in Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

I need to perform a task on every artifact added to our Sonatype Nexus repository. Is it possible to get informed about added artifacts or to query for all artifacts added since a given date/time?

Comment: You can go via the [RSS feed of Nexus](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/using-sect-feeds.html) which also gives you access to some interesting URL's like http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/feeds/recentlyChangedFiles or http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/feeds/recentlyDeployedArtifacts?count=100 ? BTW: What kind of task do you need to perform on those artifacts?

Comment: I put the jar and the sources.jar into a scanning program which feeds some information into a database.

Comment: Hm..Either a job for a post build step in a CI solution like jenkins or might be an idea for a plugin in Nexus...?

Comment: It could be a step for build or release, but this would require to call it from a strange legacy software. A nexus plugin might be an idea, I haven't checked yet how you develop those.

Comment: Writing a small plugin is the best approach.  The "virusscan" plugin here has most of the code you need:  https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-example-plugins/